# Asking a new question doesn't navigate to it, and leaving the draft on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, asking-questions, draft

I tried to ask a new question on SE Meta. After submitting it, the app showed a popup "*The question can't be loaded*". Retrying doesn't work.

When asking another question, the app thinks I still have a question draft, and asks me if I want to resume. The old question's data is still visible.

Comment: Now, it seems to have worked. Hmm, perhaps some delay in posting? The resume question part seems valid though.

Comment: I've actually had this happen before, but not on a consistent basis

Comment: I know this is an old bug report, but I just want to know if this issue is still reproducible on your side or not. The first issue is probably dupe of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238268/cannot-find-some-answers-in-mobile-app/238271#238271), while the second is questionable on current latest version (v1.0.83).