# Cannot find some answers in mobile app

Tags: bug, android-app

I posted an [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36452/344) to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12760/converting-a-string-to-lower-case-without-built-in-to-lower-functions) from my laptop, but I cannot find it in the mobile app on my Android phone. When I select it in my profile, I get the following error:

> The answer wasn't found. It may have been deleted.

## Update 1

After posting this question from my phone, I got a similar error:

> The question cannot be found, it may have been deleted.

The latter went away a few minutes later.

## Update 2

I'm getting the same error when trying to view a comment on [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36416) to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36218/input-a-number-and-return-day-of-week?page=2&tab=votes) from my inbox. Looks like an issue related to post-page-1 answers.

Comment: If you know the version number of the app, please post it here. I have been seeing this error for a long time now. Last time I saw it today, on Sep 25, with version 1.0.50. Check the screenshots I posted [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240005/official-stackexchange-app-says-my-question-is-not-available). Is this what you have been seeing?

Comment: I'm on 1.0.48. That's one of the errors I've encountered, but I'm seeing the errors about answers more often, probably because I don't post many questions.

Comment: Okay. It would seem strange that they would change the wording in the error message, but not address the issue here. What you describe here is pretty much what I have been seeing for a long time now. Now, I don't use the SE app that much at all. In fact, I use it mainly to get notifications. For posting questions or answers I use a computer with proper keyboard (because I type so much). But I will try posting some answers using the app and see what happens. Thanks for the update.

Comment: It might be just that I remembered the error message wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue from our database setup (writes from the API go to a "master" database, reads are from a "slave read-only" database, and it takes a few seconds to take things from master to the read-onlys) -- you should not be seeing it when you post an answer or question since in that case we should be directly getting the result from the API and displaying it to you. You might however see this if you immediately do a refresh after submitting your post or answer, since the refresh reads from the read-only database which might be a bit delayed.

It looks like this is currently not how the app is functioning, and posting a question or answer does actually show a "not found" screen, which is a bug. This should be fixed soon. I'll update this answer when it has.

Comment: Please see the update to my question.

Comment: Over a year later, still "soon"?

Comment: Any chance to look into it again? People keep reporting this for long time.