# Question not available in Android app

Tags: support, android-app, deleted-questions

What does it mean when the app says this?

> This question is not available it may have been deleted.

Comment: That the question has been deleted. Or that a unicorn broke your Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the question is deleted...

Deleted posts are still visible to 10K users (which you aren't on any site), and you when it was your own post.

The API which is used by the mobile apps can't access deleted posts. Not even your own. This is only possible using the main or mobile site.

Another thing it could mean is what I find a bug. The API is readonly. It uses a in-sync version of the real database. If you post a question it has to insert it into the real database and sync it back to the API database. The delay sometimes causes this message too. [(Source)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238271/245360)